# ASP MVC 5 - Link 2 models together using a common field

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys, key

I have 2 database tables that aren't under my control that need to be linked in my MVC project.  The linking is 1-to-many (1 = PoolList, Many = ClassA).

The first model:

```
public partial class ClassA
{
    public int lg_ID { get; set; }        
    public string lg_pool { get; set; }
    public string carpet { get; set; }        
}
```

The second model (this table is for the distinct list of lg_pool's):

```
public partial class PoolList
{
    public int lg_pool_ID { get; set; }        
    public string lg_pool { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to link the **ClassA.lg_pool** to the **PoolList.lg_pool**.  The desire is to have the Views for **ClassA** show a drop-down list containing only the **lg_pool** values.

I know that the DataAnnotations Key/ForeignKey exist but am not sure how to link when the **PoolList.lg_pool_ID** field is irrelevant because it's not contained in the **ClassA** model.

Answer (score 0):

C# Asp.Net Mvc does not support passing two models to a view. But you can have a ModelView which holds both models and pass that to the view. In the bellow example, You can pass ViewModelAB to the view.

```
class A
{
}
class B
{
}

class ViewModelAB
{
    A _A{set;get;}
    List<B> _Bs{set;get;}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bewar.  I only want to display a view for ClassA.  The 'lg_pool' field on the view should be a dropdown pulling from PoolList.

Comment: OK still you need to have a ViewModel which contains both classes one is the lg_pool the other is the poolList which is used for filling the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting ago at the secondary principal model in this way you have all model properties.

```
Public class modelA
{
} 
Public class modelB : modelA
{
}
```